# Creating a loop when words does not exist

Tags: powershell

In this first part of the code, I mark the existance of each file:
It marks 'true' / 'false' in each line:

```
Get-Content $list | select @{n= 'path';e={$_}}, @{n ='Exists'; e={Test-Path -LiteralPath $_}} 
| out-file $list_exists
```

In some situations this is not working.

I have created this `while` - loop for testing if 'true' and 'false' is missing from `$list_exists`.

```
$match = 'true', 'false'

$test = Get-ChildItem $list_exists | Select-String $match -quiet
while($test -eq "True")

{
"Yes, while is working"
exit
}

"After loop"
exit
```

Please help me to figure out, how to make this loop run.

As you can see, I need to create a while command, that activates the loop when 'true' and 'false' is missing from $list_exists.

Comment: It feels like some context is missing here. Why are you writing this data to a file in the first place? What is the purpose of checking (and remembering) which files exist or not? What's gonna happen next?

Comment: Hi Mathias
Thank you for your response.

I have thousands of files and pictures on different hard disks, and I'm in the middle of extracting theese files and deleting duplicate files. 
Weeee! What a task! 
After extraction af all the files from hundreds of directories, i have created this script for deleting the files, that I've already registered. 
In some situations, the script is unable to mark true / false. 
This is not because of the length of the paths, and I haven't figured out why this is happening. 
SO - I need to figure out when true / false is not working.

Comment: Why use `Out-File` to store **objects** to a file? The best thing to do here is to use `Exort-Csv` to get a structures file where everything is ordered under colums 'Path' and 'Exists'

Comment: @Larry So the resulting files has multiple rows, but there's just a blank space where you expect `true`/`false` to be, or... something else?

Comment: I have a feeling that it might be worth comparing against a MD5 reference to insure any files with the same filename are not deleted. The `Get-FileHash` might come in handy here.

Comment: Hi Mathias changing from Out-File to Export-Csv solved my issue. Now the true / false mark works for all files.
I think it´s the combination of using Out-File in combination with Test-Path, that created the issue.
Thank You ;-)